# Conditional Count Loop Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out where my mistake is in the following code which is about guessing a word.

If I type in the missing word, `"ghost"`, it should end the game but it continues to ask for it.

Where is my mistake?

```
number = 0
missword = "ghost"
while number < 3:
    guess = input("What is the missing word? ")
    if guess != "ghost":
        print("Try again")
        number = number + 1
    elif guess == missword:
        print("Game Over")
    else:
        print("Game over")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All your loop does is print, you need a break statement:

```
number=0
missword="ghost"
while number<3:
    guess = input("What is the missing word? ")
    if guess!="ghost": # Assuming you actually want this to be missword?
        print("Try again")
        number += 1 # Changed to a unary operator, slightly faster.
    elif guess==missword:
        print("Game Over")
        break
    else:
        print("Game over")
        # Is this ever useful?
```

`break` exits a loop before the exit condition has been satisfied. `Print` on the other hand simply outputs text to `stdout`, nothing else.

Comment: Thank you Scironic - Brain Freeze moment!

Comment: No problem Uday :-) don't forget to tick if this is the correct answer so future users find it easier to navigate.